# MySQL returns bad result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question about SELECT FROM WHERE statement, which returns me bad result.

Here is my table called friends:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
| lastname | firstname | callprefix | phone  | region | zip   |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
| Lužný    | Bob       |        602 | 111222 | OL     | 79821 |
| Matyáš   | Bob       |        773 | 123456 | BR     | NULL  |
| Strouhal | Fido      |        300 | 343434 | ZL     | 76701 |
| Přikryl  | Tom       |        581 | 010101 | PL     | 72000 |
| Černý    | Franta    |        777 | 000999 | OL     | 79801 |
| Zavadil  | Olda      |        911 | 111311 | OL     | 79604 |
| Berka    | Standa    |        604 | 111234 | ZL     | 72801 |
| Vlcik    | BbB       |        736 | 555444 | KV     | 35210 |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
```

And here is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE region <= 'z';
```

I would expect that the rows with region ZL should be present, but they are not. Can you please tell me why?

Result is:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
| lastname | firstname | callprefix | phone  | region | zip   |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
| Lužný    | Bob       |        602 | 111222 | OL     | 79821 |
| Matyáš   | Bob       |        773 | 123456 | BR     | NULL  |
| Přikryl  | Tom       |        581 | 010101 | PL     | 72000 |
| Černý    | Franta    |        777 | 000999 | OL     | 79801 |
| Zavadil  | Olda      |        911 | 111311 | OL     | 79604 |
| Vlcik    | BbB       |        736 | 555444 | KV     | 35210 |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
```

When I try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE region >= 'z';
```

the result contains both rows with region = 'ZL'

????

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you assume that `<=` works like that?

Comment: USE `Where region LIKE 'Z%' OR SIMPLY LIKE 'ZL' or your syntax only <= to_upper('z%')`

Answer (score 1):

Because "ZL" is greater than "Z." Z is just one character so will only return values less that Z or with the value of Z. What are you trying to achieve with this query?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please tell me why?

If you add a record where region is `Z`, and sorted those rows alphabetically by region, would you expect `ZL` to come before or after `Z`? Obviously it would come after, so it does not meet your criteria.

If you want to only consider the first character, then *add that to your criteria*:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE LEFT(region,1) <= 'Z';
```

I would also make `Z` explicitly a capital letter in case your database settings make it a case-sensitive search.

Comment: I am asking because of SQL learnbook which contains this query and the author expects result described above. So that is a huge bug in that book.

So I assume that the less and greater operators compare the whole string with the 'z' letter in this case.

Thank you for your answers.

FYI I took this example from czech version of book "Learn the SQL in 28 days" written by Ryan Stephens, Ron Plew and Arie D. Jones. I suppose in english version there are no mistakes like this.

Comment: It's also possible that _some_ SQL engines will perform the way the book implies, but I would not rely on that behavior and make your intent explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
`SELECT * FROM friends WHERE region <= 'zl';`?

From the computer's perspective, `'z' < 'zl'`